# How can the {x,y,z} points that fall on the outer boundary of a set of values be selected and smoothly surfaced?

Tags: graphics, list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis, computational-geometry, mesh

For a given set of x,y,z values, that may, or may not form a uniform shape, how can the center of the data cloud be found, and the surface points be located and a solid smooth surface created from them?  In some cases a set of points may create intersections of shapes but there are no holes to deal with in the data.

```
x=RandomReal[1,{400,3}];

ListPointPlot3D[x]
```

[image: scatterplot]

here's a 2D version of a bSpline interpolation function I have used for joining the surface points smoothly after dividing them in painful ways.  Running Mathematica 8.04

```
ParameterAverageKnots[deg_, data_] := 
 Module[{param = data[[All, 1]]}, 
  Join[ConstantArray[param[[1]], deg + 1], 
   Table[1/deg Sum[param[[i]], {i, j, j + deg - 1}], {j, 2, 
     Length[param] - deg}], ConstantArray[param[[-1]], deg + 1]]]

UniformKnots[deg_, data_] := 
 Rescale[Join[ConstantArray[0, deg], 
   Range[0, 1, 1/(Length[data] - deg)], ConstantArray[1, deg]], {0, 
   1}, {data[[1, 1]], data[[-1, 1]]}]

UnclampedKnots[deg_, data_] := 
 Rescale[Range[Length[data] + deg + 1], {deg + 1, 
   Length[data] + 1}, {data[[1, 1]], data[[-1, 1]]}]

BasisMatrix[deg_, data_, knotfunc_] := 
 With[{knots = knotfunc[deg, data]}, 
  Table[BSplineBasis[{deg, knots}, j - 1, data[[i, 1]]], {i, 
    Length[data]}, {j, Length[data]}]]             

BSplineInterpolation2D[data_, deg_, knotfunc_] := 
  Module[{knots, m, sol},
   knots = knotfunc[deg, data];
   m = BasisMatrix[deg, data, knotfunc];
   sol = LinearSolve[m, data[[All, 2]]];
   BSplineFunction[sol, 1, SplineDegree -> deg, SplineKnots -> knots]];

degree = 3;
pts = RandomReal[5, 10] // Sort
data = Transpose[{Range[10], pts}]
f = BSplineInterpolation2D[data, degree, UniformKnots]
Plot[f[t], {t, 1, 10}, Epilog -> {Red, Point@data}]
```

[image: bslplineInterpolation]

can it be extended to this purpose?  Of course there's still that tough part about getting the outer points to surface, and after splining how to surface the form.

To review this issue again after all of the great input and trials, the results show that for some very similar shapes the solution did not work.  Here are 2 examples:[image: Cohesive results]

Now for slightly changed data with a similar shape:[image: Non-Cohesive results]

In both of these examples the data points provide very reasonable shapes to surface. One works, the other fails... thoughts?

The failed test data can be downloaded [here](https://github.com/downloads/stackmma/Attachments/rhalDatafail.txt).

Comment: Very interesting problem. Using `ListSurfacePlot3D` with the right subset of points would do the graphic part. Getting that subset is the hard part.

Comment: Please post both pointsets (as shown in your edit) somewhere in the 'net.

Comment: I see you placed a bounty on this.  As belisarius said, you should post the point set, otherwise we can't test.  Export to WDX and upload somewhere.

Comment: How do you define the surface? Do you mean the convex hull or something else? And what is a uniform shape?

Comment: @Szabolcs the data sets are about 1500 x 3 points.  Is that too big for this forum?  On another note, what I see in error checks is that the surface=TetGenConvexHull[data3D]; portion is clearly at fault and doesn't return the surface only points.

Comment: @RHall Ideally you could upload it to some other site such as http://ge.tt/ and put a link in the question.  You can export to WDX or as `Table`.

Comment: @belisarius No idea where that can happen.  I do not have a personal blog or site for the post.  If there is a public one I'll be happy to put it there for access

Comment: @Sjoerd C. de Vries a convex hull is an accurate definition.  As you can see the previous method does not provide an accurate representation.

Comment: Ok Thank you! @Szabolcs the test data that failed is located here http://ge.tt/2cdtt8F/v/0?c

Comment: @RHall It works fine.  `data = Import[
  "http://w221470.open.ge.tt/1/files/2cdtt8F/0/blob?download", 
  "Table"]; {pts, surf} = TetGenConvexHull[data]; Graphics3D@
 GraphicsComplex[pts, Polygon[surf]]`  You need to use the point set returned by `TetGenConvexHull` because it removes duplicates from it (which there are present in your data)

Comment: This also explains why they changed the behaviour to return the point coordinates as well as the polygons.

Comment: @Szabolcs great thanks very much! We have a winner!

Comment: Thanks for the (undeserved) bounty !

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Not sure about the creation of a "smooth" surface. But from Mma help, you may create a convex hull in 3D by using **TetGenConvexHull**

```
Needs["TetGenLink`"]
data3D = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 3}];
Graphics3D[Point[data3D]];
surface = TetGenConvexHull[data3D];
(* TetGenConvexHull was changed sometime between 8.0.0 and 8.0.4.
   Uncomment the following line only if you are using 8.0.4. *)
(* surface = Last[surface] *)
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[data3D, Polygon[surface]]]
```

[image]

HTH ... I am not really sure ...

To get the points in the convex hull, you could use for example:

```
  pointss = data3D[[Union@Flatten@surface]]
```

Comment: not bad, but provides some rather spikey results when the data is not as well formed.

Comment: @RHall Yep. But I am not aware of a way for using **BSplineSurface[]** as an interpolation (there is one out there ... for sure)

Comment: @RHall Darn! If that works, please post an answer!

Comment: not quite @belisarius this is only 2D and still requires the surface points.  Getting closer though, thanks for the ideas!

Comment: @RHall See my edit, pls.

Comment: What's your version of Mathematica? I cannot run it without the edit I did.

Comment: With `Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[data3D, Polygon[surface[[2]]]]]` I can run it too. `TetGenConvexHull` returns me to vectors, the points and the surface polygons.

Comment: @belisarius The documentation uses a slightly different syntax: see TetGenLink/ref/TetGenConvexHull: `{pts, surface} = TetGenConvexHull[data3D]; Graphics3D[
 GraphicsComplex[pts, Polygon[surface]]]`
Your syntax gives me a lot of jumbled polygons.

Comment: belisarius: I believe you have 8.0.0.  Maybe this is another case of functionality changing between minor versions.  In 8.0.4, `TetGenConvexHull` returns a list with two elements: the point coordinates and the point indices defining the surface polygons.  It looks like, your version only returns the latter.  So for me to be able to run it, @FJRA's edit is necessary.  You could add a note to the answer about this problem.  I think TetGenLink is primarily for internal use ... perhaps that's why it changed.

Comment: I tried to fix the situation, please review my edit.

Comment: @Szabolcs, same results as before thanks very much for your contribution though this is a sticky problem!

Comment: @FRJA looks good to me in 8.04!  Nicely formed to some real sample data!

Comment: @Yves Klett Another excellent result! But it also returns the points and poly's!  Thanks very much!

Comment: @Szabolcs the edited code actually does work beautifully for me on 8.04  thanks very much for your time and review! after a few hours of comments it's tough to see who did what! :)

Comment: +1 but... is there a public 3D convex hull function for v7?

Comment: @Szabolcs et al. Roger. Version 8.0.0.0 here

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No AFAIK, but if need arises, you could roll your own: http://tetgen.berlios.de/

Comment: I thought this was a solved problem, but after further review, changes to the data that's being surfaced dramatically affect the ability of the function above to create a surface that is cohesive.  Only a few data sets provide good results.  I'm now looking at a NURBS or bSplineSurface solutions to provide a more concise way to surface different sets of data points.

Comment: Just to understand ... What do you mean by "cohesive"? Can you post some examples? This finds the Convex Hull points. I thought that was what you was after

Comment: Probably not the correct way to describe the problem @belisarius.  By Cohesive in this case, I mean the surface holds together as a unit, Ive posted some examples of 2 similar data sets where one works and one does not, for no visible reason other than the slight change in distance between the points in one area of the field. Thanks for your review!

Comment: @szabolcs I don't think tetgen is for internal use, I think it's a forerunner tool to be used in concert with the announced MathModellica.

Comment: @sjoerd the docs say "It is used automatically by Mathematica for various operations, such as interpolation in three-dimensional convex domains".  Indeed, for linear interpolation we need to construct a Delaunay triangulation (or whatever that's called in 3d), and that's one of the things TetGen can do

Answer (score 6):

If what you want is a nice smooth surface of the outer boundary, then in *Mathematica* 10.2 you can do the following:

```
data3D = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 3}];  (* generate some random point *)
cvx = ConvexHullMesh[data3D]            (* get the outer boundary *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now we can `Discretize` the surface and smooth it in one go:

```
smooth = DiscretizeRegion[cvx,  MeshCellStyle -> {{1, All} -> RGBColor[1/2, 0, 0],      
                 {2, All} -> RGBColor[1/2, 0, 0]}, PlotTheme -> "SmoothShading"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

OR without the triangles:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can recover the surface points from `MeshCoordinates[smooth]`