# How could a non-convex volume joining the outer points of a 3D anatomical model be created?

Tags: plotting, visualization, mesh, segmentation

I am trying to visualise segmented anatomical models in 3D. Currently, my attemps are very basic, like the following code. What other ways could you come up with? `ListSurfacePlot3D` doesn't work that well. The files contain lines with the coordinates of each voxel (x,y,z).

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

prop = Import[#, "Table"] & /@ {"http://leaf.dragonflybsd.org/~beket/skull.txt", 
"http://leaf.dragonflybsd.org/~beket/brainwhite.txt"};

genPoint[{x_, y_, z_}] := 
 Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Red], EdgeForm[], Lighting -> "Neutral", 
   Sphere[{x, y, z}, 1/5]}]

ParallelTable[
 Show[genPoint /@ prop[[k]], ViewPoint -> {1.3, 2.4, 2.}, ImageSize -> 300],
    {k, 1, Length@prop}]
```

[image: A 3D segmented skull]

Comment: What is the problem with the image you show and what kind of visualisation would you expect? Are you looking for surfaces instead of points, such as joining all outer points with surfaces?

Comment: Yes, a surface joining all outer points would be very nice. `ConvexHullMesh` didn't cut it for me, because I lose the information of cavities.

Comment: I think that "finding the outer points of a list of points defining a non-convex volume" is an interesting question in itself. If that's really what you want, you should probably rephrase the question as such. In that case, somehow related questions:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/89725/how-to-find-points-along-the-inner-and-outer-edge-of-a-ring-along-a-specific-dir and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2998/how-can-the-x-y-z-points-that-fall-on-the-outer-boundary-of-a-set-of-values-be.

Comment: Thank you for the references @anderstood! I'll study them and come back again.

Comment: Just a head's up, you can get decent visualizations with `Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Skull"]["MeshRegion"]` and `Entity["AnatomicalStructure", "Skull"]["Graphics3D"]`

Comment: You might also check `ExampleData[{"Geometry3D", "StanfordBunny"}]` which provides a nice rendering or explore the documentation related to `Printout3D`, you might stumble upon functions to build a printable model from your list of points, and so also 3D viewing (I don't know much about MMA 3D viewing so I can't be more precise).

Comment: See also https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/AnatomyPlot3D.html, if you just want to _visualise_ anatomy.

Comment: Thanks folks for the great references. I need to plot the data that I am given, not just built-in anatomical data (which look awesome by the way).

Comment: @Zet - if you aren't able to make this work using RunnyKine's answer in the marked duplicate, we can reopen the question.  I was able to get [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4dUq.png) from his code using the input `meshregion = alphaShapes[data3D, 2.4];
Graphics3D[
 GraphicsComplex[MeshCoordinates@meshregion, 
  MeshCells[meshregion, 2]]]`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use *Mathematica*'s curated data instead?

```
Entity["AnatomicalStructure","Skull"]["Graphics3D"]
```

[image]

Comment: David, the OP specified that they have to plot *their own data set* specifically, rather than a generic one.